# How to translate plurals of a model in the Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Django application with a model called `Topic`. I want to translate the plural of this model in the Django admin (see the red ellipse in the screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot]

In order to do this, I did following:

1) Added a *Meta* class to the model in *models.py*:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('topic')
        verbose_name_plural = _('topics')
```

2) Ran `django-admin.py makemessages -l ru-RU`, which generated a file `locale/ru/django.po`.

3) Added translations to the `django.po` file:

```
msgid "topic"
msgstr "Тема"

msgid "topics"
msgstr "Темы"
```

4) Ran `django-admin.py compilemessages`.

5) Changed `settings.py` so that there are following settings there:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

ugettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
  ('ru-RU', ugettext('Russian')),
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True
```

But it still doesn't work (the marked lettering in the admin still appears in English, not in Russian).

What can I do in order to fix this?

**Update 1 (28.09.2013 13:26):** Maybe something is wrong with my directory structure. Here it is:

[image: Directory structure]

Answer (score 4):

1. Probably `locale` dir does not live in your app's directory or is not defined in `LOCALE_PATHS`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations
2. It should generate a file `locale/ru-RU/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`.

Comment: `locale/ru-RU/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` was there already. Adding `LOCALE_PATHS = ("D:/dev/my-site/locale",)` to `settings.py` didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a better practice to add the app translations within the app folder itself, this makes it portable and easier to find. It may also help you with your problem.

Create a "locale" folder within your app:

```
my-site/opinions/locale/
```

Standing within your app folder, run the "django-admin.py makemessages -l ru-RU" comand. It should create the django.po file with the the needed translations in blank.

After you fill the missing translations, run "django-admin.py compilemessages" and restart your server just in case.

Also, in your settings.py file, don't use hard-coded strings for your folders, it's a better practice to get them dynamically

```
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'locale'), )
```

This last code will assume that the locale folder is with the settings.py file.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work. Maybe it's easier to implement own localized page for editing these entities than tweaking the admin localization.

Comment: I added my directory structure to the question. Maybe it's wrong and causes these problems.

Comment: Opinions id a Django app? Where si your settings.py file?

Comment: `settings.py` file is located in `history-site\history_site`.

Comment: Ok, you seem to be working with an old Django structure. Have you tried if your translations work outside the admin?

Answer (score 0):

I tried Django 1.7.

I tried the same method, but didn't work at the first time,  after some debugging into Django, I found some hints and found the solution, there should be some document in Django for locale names, actually there are some rules not documented.

And in my test,  only messages under project can be loaded,  all messages in app cannot be translated.

I tried print _("") in the same index() method in my app's view.  only msgid in settings.py file can be translated.

The code looks like below:

def index(request):

```
print request.LANGUAGE_CODE
str_msg = _("Welcome to poll list!")   ## this keep English output, only appears in app
print str_msg
str_msg = _("Simplified Chinese")     ## this one worked, it appears in settings.py
print str_msg
context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
           'message': str_msg}
....
```

After checked the some Django code, I found it allowed only the locale names given under page

https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/conf/locale

Please note the directory names, there is no 'ru-RU', no 'zh-cn'.

code in gettext.py:

```html
def translation(domain, localedir=None, languages=None,
                class_=None, fallback=False, codeset=None):
    if class_ is None:
        class_ = GNUTranslations
    mofiles = find(domain, localedir, languages, all=1)
    if not mofiles:
        if fallback:
            return NullTranslations()
        raise IOError(ENOENT, 'No translation file found for domain', domain)
```

I fixed my own problem by changing 'zh-cn' to 'zh_CN', then ran the following commands:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l zh_CN
```

copied django.po file from folder '/zh-cn/LC_MESSAGES/' to folder '/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES',  to keep my translations.

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

then,

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Now everything is OK!

So, I think to change from 'ru-RU' to 'ru' may solve your problem.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm using `ru` instead of `ru-RU`. But it doesn't work. To be correctly it works, but not for all models. Some models are translated, but some don't. (I've provided all translations in `django.po` and models are from the same app)